# Google Assistant routine only executing first command?

Tags: voice-recognition, voice-command, google-assistant, google-maps-navigation, google-voice-actions

I have a Google Assistant routine with 2 custom actions: `Navigate to home` and `Play Spotify music`.

For some reason, only the first action ever completes when I execute the routine via voice command. If I swap the actions around, the first one always completes. So if I have playing music first, it plays music but does not navigate. Vice versa, if I have navigating first, it navigates but does not play music.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: [Disabling Digital Wellbeing seems to fix the problem for some](https://support.google.com/assistant/thread/406090?hl=en)

Comment: @beeshyams unfortunately, I don't have Digital Wellbeing setup (unless I am missing something, but I checked in settings and didn't see anything enabled).